# Consul-Template filter if not match

Tags: templates, filter, consul

Is there a way to use consul template to filter if something is not a match?

Something like

```
{{services NOT "@east-aws"}}
...
```

I'm not finding it in the [repository readme](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

```
{{ range services }}
  {{ if ne .Name "name-of-service" }}
    ......
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: You forgot to accept your own answer. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: If you want to check env variables  you can do something like {{ if ne (env "ENVIRONMENT_ID")  "prod" }}